Firebase Authentication Error: "Error (auth/configuration-not-found)" in React Native App
I'm developing a React Native app using Firebase for authentication, and I'm encountering an error: "Error (auth/configuration-not-found)" when I attempt to check if an email is registered using fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(). My Firebase configuration appears to be set up correctly, with Email/Password sign-in enabled in the Firebase console. I've verified my API key and app ID, and I've initialized Firebase authentication properly. However, the error persists. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Pressable, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import Colors from '../constants/Colors'; 
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth} from '../firebaseConfig';

export default function Signup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [focusedField, setFocusedField] = useState(null);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const validateEmail = (email) => {
        const re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
      };

  
    const handleContinue = async () => {
        if (!validateEmail(email)) {
            Alert.alert("Error", "Please enter a valid email address.");
            return;
        }

        console.log('Auth Object:', auth);
        console.log('Email being checked:', email);


        try {
            const signInMethods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email);
            
            if (signInMethods.length === 0) {
                // No account associated with this email, proceed to create account
                router.push('/createAcc');
            } else {
                // Email is already in use
                Alert.alert("Error", "This email is already registered. Please use a different email.");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Create your account</Text>
            
            <TextInput
                style={[
                    styles.input,
                    focusedField === 'Email' && styles.inputFocused, // Apply focus style
                ]}
                placeholder="Email"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                value={email} // Bind the input to the email state
                onChangeText={setEmail} // Update the email state on change
                onFocus={() => setFocusedField('Email')}
                onBlur={() => setFocusedField(null)}
            />
            
            <Pressable style={styles.continueButton} onPress={handleContinue}>
                <Text style={styles.continueButtonText}>Continue</Text>
                <MaterialIcons name="arrow-forward" size={24} color="white" />
            </Pressable>
            
            <View style={styles.orContainer}>
                <View style={styles.line} />
                <Text style={styles.orText}>OR</Text>
                <View style={styles.line} />
            </View>
            
            <Pressable style={styles.googleButton}>
                <FontAwesome name="google" size={24} color="white" />
                <Text style={styles.googleButtonText}>Continue with Google</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_GRAY,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    input: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        borderColor: Colors.SECONDARY_GRAY, // Corrected the typo here from SECONDAY_GRAY
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 8,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    inputFocused: {
        borderColor: Colors.ACCENT_ORANGE, 
        borderWidth: 3,
    },
    continueButton: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.ACCENT_ORANGE,
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 10,
        width: '100%',
    },
    continueButtonText: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 18,
        marginRight: 8,
    },
    orContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: 10,
        width: '100%',
    },
    orText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        marginVertical: 30,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
    },
    line: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    },
    googleButton: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: Colors.ACCENT_GREEN,
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 10,
        width: '100%',
    },
    googleButtonText: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 18,
        marginLeft: 8,
    },
    googleLogo: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
    },
});


